# node.js receive PDF file and print

Tags: node.js, file, pdf, upload

I try to create a endpoint API which can:

1. receive a PDF docuent comming from a standard html form
2. stores the pdf file
3. does a print out with pdf-to-printer
4. deletes the temporary pdf file from point 2

Thats the main structure at the moment - i cant get the file post solved...

```
import express from "express";
import ptp from "pdf-to-printer";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

ptp.getPrinters().then(console.log);

app.post('', express.raw({ type: 'application/pdf' }), async(req, res) => {

    const options = {
        printer: "Microsoft Print to PDF"
        //pages: "1-3,5",
        //scale: "fit",
      };

    /*if (req.query.printer) {
        options.printer = req.query.printer;
    }*/
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(`./tmp/${Math.random().toString(36).substr(7)}.pdf`);

    fs.writeFileSync(tmpFilePath, req.body, 'binary');
    await ptp.print(tmpFilePath, options);
    fs.unlinkSync(tmpFilePath);

    res.status(204);
    res.send();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`PDF Printing Service listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

My "File Upload" is just a regular HTML Form - but I cant get it working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PDF Printer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:3000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="someExpressFiles" id="myFile" size="500" />
        <input type="text" name="title" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Error I get is:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object

Comment: The error you're encountering is likely due to how you're trying to read and handle the uploaded PDF file. When using express.raw() or express.json(), the incoming data is not guaranteed to be a string or a Buffer directly. In your code, you were using express.raw() which might be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Golam, as I´m new to node - what would be the best way to get it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be fair i am also new but you can try this with multer

```
npm install multer
```

we're using req.file.path to get the path to the uploaded PDF file, which is stored temporarily by multer. This should resolve the "**TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]**" issue you were encountering

```
import express from "express";
import ptp from "pdf-to-printer";
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs/promises";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./tmp",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, "pdf_" + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/print', upload.single("pdfFile"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pdfFilePath = req.file.path;
    const options = {
      printer: "Microsoft Print to PDF"
      // Other print options here
    };

    await ptp.print(pdfFilePath, options);
    await fs.unlink(pdfFilePath);

    res.status(200).send("PDF printed successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Error printing PDF.");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`PDF Printing Service listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much Golam - It´s running perfectly fine!!!! Compliment